# Android: how notify an app that a service has been uninstalled

Tags: android, service

I have an app that binds to a service (application and service lives in two separate apk). What happens if the service's apk is uninstalled while my app is still running?

Is there something that can notify my app? I can't simply filter on ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intent because the service could change his name (apk name).

Answer (score 0):

Changing apk name doesn't affect ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intent, but package name does. You can register a BroadcastReceive to filter the event caused by uninstalling apk.

Comment: currently my app does what you suggest, I have registered the BroadcastReceive, but I need a more generic notification. The app will be released and will not change, but for some reasons the service could be change and released with other apk name/data.

Comment: More generic notification? The package name that identifies the application. If that changes, then it is a new application. You want to communicate with a specific app, so package name should be good for you.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if the service's apk is uninstalled while my app is still
>   running?

Android will stop the Service before uninstalling it, so your active connections will be closed with `ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected()`.

> Is there something that can notify my app?

ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED should work. You will get the full package name of the application being uninstalled, the name of the apk does not matter in this situation.